# How to get the lines that were executed in PHP?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I would like to get the lines that were executed in a really big function (more than 3k lines) after a specific request. I'm using PHPStorm and xdebug.

xdebug provides functions `xdebug_start_code_coverage()` and `xdebug_get_code_coverage()`, they are doing exactly what I want, but they are returning an array with the line numbers which is not very convenient. I need to get a visual representation, like marking executed lines with green in the IDE or something like that. Is there a way to integrate this into PHPStorm? Or maybe there is an alternative that will help to achieve similar result?

Comment: as you said, the xdebug functions give you the line numbers. so parse the files and get the lines if you want to do anything with it.

Comment: PhpStorm has some integration with PHPUnit unit tests. I don't know if visualising code coverage is part of that, but you could try looking into it.